# How to isolate query to find particular fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-like

Here is the database I'm using: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ArJekOQpal0JFIr1h3NXYcFVngnCNUxg/view?usp=sharing

I'm trying to create a query to output the academics (acnum) who are **ONLY**
interested in "Data" (descrip) fields.

I tried this:

```
select acnum
from interest
where upper(descrip) like '%DATA%';
```

It partly works, it finds the academics(acnum) that are interested in fields(descrip) with 'Data' in their names, but it also lists the academics(acnum) that have other interests besides 'Data' fields, how do I find academics(acnum) that are interested **ONLY** in 'Data' fields(descrip)?

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide `result data` and `expected data`

Answer (score 0):

To get *academics(acnum) that are interested ONLY in 'Data' fields(descrip)* you could use following query with some aggregation to satisfy your criteria

```
SELECT acnum
FROM interest
GROUP BY acnum
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(descrip) LIKE '%DATA%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: If using MySQL, then this can be abbreviated to SUM(x LIKE '%y%')

Answer (score 0):

Another approach -- if you want more columns about the academic -- is `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from academics a
where not exists (select 1
                  from interest i
                  where a.acnum = i.acnum and upper(descrip) like '%DATA%'
                 );
```